# Search specific key's value from a json field database entry using eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hello everyone please I am working on a system and need to add a query that receives a search term stored with the variable $search and fetch all matching values for a specific key in a json field from  database.

I have tried the code bellow

```
$query = Book::whereJsonContains('book_details->author',['like'=>"%{$search}%"])->get();
```

Book is my model, book_details is the json field name and author is the key. I want to retrieve every book with authors related to the search term

Comment: so, what is the error or issue you are having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel, you can perform a query that retrieves all matching values for a specific key in a JSON field by utilizing the whereJsonContains method. A revised version of your code could look like this:

```
$query = Book::whereJsonContains('book_details->author', $search)->get();
```

This query will return all Book records where the value of the author key in the book_details JSON field contains the search term stored in the $search variable.

Note that you don't need to wrap the search term in % characters, as the whereJsonContains method performs a case-insensitive search for matching values by default.